# Getting error in pom.xml after enabling the debug in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to view the ddl generated by spring boot and hence configured "debug=true" in the application properties file, but immediately there is a error in the pom.xml as below. Not sure what is the reason for this error and how to resolve this. Will be grateful to the community for helping me to resolve this.

```
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: *newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0) (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources:default-resources:process-resources)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment in answer here:
[Spring boot project crashes if I add any values to application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69844566/spring-boot-project-crashes-if-i-add-any-values-to-application-properties)

Suggests: mvn clean

(worked for me)

Comment: Is this a duplicate question of that?